# CSS Grid with auto-fit and minmax. At a line full width on each line

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a css grid and would like to at a border on every new row or even better a div with full width (100vw). The border should be on the full screen (no padding left and right).
The container is fluid with a big padding on each side.

Code:

```
    <div className="container-fluids mx-auto mt-20 px-40">
      <main className="grid grid-cols-new4 thumbnailView">
        {artworks.map((artwork: Artwork, index: number) => {
          return (
            <div key={index} className="border-b-black border-b mb-12">
              <Thumbnail props={artwork} />
              <div className="mx-auto w-full mt-2 pb-1 font-bold text-xs">{artwork.attributes.artist?.data?.attributes?.Fullname}</div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </main>
    </div>

Custom-Style: 'new4': 'repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15em, 1fr))',
```

My current version: https://endearing-yeot-d62a2a.netlify.app/

Any help would be great. Cheers, carol

Comment: Please add enough code to the question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think it's no possible inside a css grid with auto-fix and minmax.
the only solution for me would be to update the loop with some div's between each row.